# builtins.AttributeError: module '_strptime' has no attribute '_strptime_datetime'

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```py
import datetime

for sale in sales_data:

    if sale[0] not in [ret[0] for ret in returns_data]:
    
        sale_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sale[1], "%Y-%m-%d")
    
        weekday = sale_date.strftime('%A')
    
        weekday_count[weekday] += 1
```

when I run it it returns
:

```
"builtins.AttributeError: module '\_strptime' has no attribute '\_strptime_datetime'"
```

I try delate one datetime from

`sale_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sale\[1\], "%Y-%m-%d")`

but it returns:

```
"builtins.AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'"
```

I want to know how to fix it.

Comment: It would be nice to see the `sales_data`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a small working example based on your question (It would be nice to see the `sales_data`'s value to say more specific answer).

**The code:**

```
import datetime

dates = ["2018-12-11", "2019-11-03"]

for sale in dates:
    sale_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sale, "%Y-%m-%d")
    weekday = sale_date.strftime('%A')
    print(weekday)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Tuesday
Sunday
```

The used python version: Python 3.11.0

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, "AttributeError: module '_strptime' has no attribute '_strptime_datetime'", typically occurs when there is a conflict with the _strptime module in certain versions of Python.

To resolve this issue, you can try to explicitly import the _strptime module.

Comment: It not work , when I import _strptime it shows"builtins.AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"